# Running a block of code from RAM instead of flash

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, flash-memory, nxp-microcontroller

In the following program, what is the meaning of the line of code

```
fnRAM_code((volatile unsigned char *)FLASH_STATUS_REGISTER); // execute the command from SRAM
```

in the below section of code. I have some idea about what is happening here,In order to overcome read while write violation, copying the code from flash to RAM using the above lines of code. But what is exact meaning of these lines.

```
static int fnProgram(unsigned long *ptrWord, unsigned long *ptr_ulWord)
{
    while ((FTFL_FSTAT & FTFL_STAT_CCIF) == 0) {}                // wait for previous commands to complete

    if ((FTFL_FSTAT & (FTFL_STAT_ACCERR | FTFL_STAT_FPVIOL | FTFL_STAT_RDCOLERR)) != 0) { // check for errors in previous command 
        FTFL_FSTAT = (FTFL_STAT_ACCERR | FTFL_STAT_FPVIOL | FTFL_STAT_RDCOLERR); // clear old errors
    }

    FTFL_FCCOB0 = FCMD_PROGRAM;                                  // enter the command sequence
    FTFL_FCCOB1 = (unsigned char)(((CAST_POINTER_ARITHMETIC)ptrWord) >> 16); // set address in flash
    FTFL_FCCOB2 = (unsigned char)(((CAST_POINTER_ARITHMETIC)ptrWord) >> 8);
    FTFL_FCCOB3 = (unsigned char)((CAST_POINTER_ARITHMETIC)ptrWord);
    FTFL_FCCOB7_4 = *ptr_ulWord++;                               // enter the long word to be programmed
    FTFL_FCCOBB_8 = *ptr_ulWord;                                 // enter the second long word to be programmed
    uDisable_Interrupt();                                        // protect this region from interrupts
        fnRAM_code((volatile unsigned char *)FLASH_STATUS_REGISTER); // execute the command from SRAM
    uEnable_Interrupt();                                         // safe to accept interrupts again
    return (FTFL_FSTAT & (FTFL_STAT_ACCERR | FTFL_STAT_FPVIOL | FTFL_STAT_MGSTAT0)); // if there was an error this will be non-zero
}
```

The only code that needs to be in RAM is this:

```
static void fnFlashRoutineInRam(volatile unsigned char *ptrFTFL_BLOCK)
{
    *ptrFTFL_BLOCK = FTFL_STAT_CCIF;                                     // launch the command - this clears the FTFL_STAT_CCIF flag (register is FTFL_FSTAT)
    while ((*ptrFTFL_BLOCK & FTFL_STAT_CCIF) == 0) {}                    // wait for the command to terminate
}
```

Comment: What is `fnRAM_code`? It is smth like [here](https://github.com/relayr/WunderBar-firmware-release/blob/master/USB_MSD_Device_bootloader_v1.0/Source/Device/app/msd_bootloader/flash_driver/flash_FTFE.c#L104)?

Comment: It is the function name

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this MCU or its c API buy at random glance I would wager it basically checking flags (which are handled by their handlers and should usually clear themselves) perhaps just a formality, then it is forming some Opcode's to be executed. I'm guessing a single Opcode's maybe where first 16 bits are 16 bit address, basically forming a valid Opcode's with its fields to do something which is ultimately inserted into section in memory. With out knowing the MCU type and architecture i can't really say too much.

Comment: If it is a function name (ie. i guess you mean identifier), then what is its function declaration? If it is a function pointer, then what is its function pointer declaration, what is its value, where does it point to? In the code i linked, `fnRAM_code` identifier is a function pointer pointing somewhere into custom SRAM location.

Comment: My very uninformed guess which is probably completely wrong, especially in light of Kamils comment above, is that it executes a function call from SRAM address which is also the current flash status register's value?

Comment: Also all cap variables like the FTLF_COBB_0 etc, usually all cap variable is used for constant or maybe some kind of significant object, similar to way program parameters first letter is canal case with lowercase first letter. And regular maybe lower scoped variables are typically just lowercasr in some software. The Opcode's is likely used somehow in the function call, buy would need more space to know how or why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like older NXP (former Freescale/Motorola) HCS08, HCS12 or Coldfire. On those devices, you have different cases when writing a flash driver: either you can execute it from flash or you cannot. This entirely depends on which "bank" the program flash belongs to: generally you cannot execute code on a MCU from the very same flash bank it is currently programming.

So ideally you put the flash programming code in another bank, but some devices only have one single flash bank. Then they provide a work-around by executing the code from RAM, which is kind of a quick & dirty fix.

Commonly they solve this by providing an array of raw data op codes. This array of op codes is copied to RAM and then they set a function pointer to point at the RAM address. I suspect `fnRAM_code` is such a function pointer. The `(volatile unsigned char *)FLASH_STATUS_REGISTER` part is simply passing on the address of the flash status register. Likely, FLASH_STATUS_REGISTER is synonymous with FSTAT.

The `uDisable_Interrupt();` and `uEnable_Interrupt();` should correspond to `asm SEI` and `asm CLI` respectively, blocking all maskable interrupts from triggering during the flash write, which would potentially cause the write to fail or the program to hang up.

There should be app notes available describing all of this in detail.

Please note that this code is very close to the hardware and relies on tons of poorly-defined behavior. I wouldn't count on it compiling as expected on anything but the Codewarrior compiler. gcc would for example spew out numerous strict aliasing bugs.

Comment: As for how to generate the op codes, you could disassemble `fnFlashRoutineInRam` and steal the code from there. This will give you the right calling convention, though you must ensure that you stack all accumulators/registers etc before using them, since the compiler-generated disassembly might take short-cuts there.